# Looking for a short scary story book! A girl (Chloe) is turned into a cat and stoned?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult, horror

I first read it in 2007 or so. Quite sure the cover was orange. There were a few books of the same style written by the same author, but this is the one I remember.

- A girl walks into an empty house and is drugged, turns into a cat. She tries to escape and it's hinted that the bad kids that like to throw stones at cats kill her
- Two boys meet a girl they both like, who pushes them to meet their fears. Ends in them both dying, one locked in a chest in a construction site being filled with cement (his fear was claustrophobia).

I may have picked up these next ones somewhere else but I *think* they're from the same book:

- A boy breaks into a farmers garden and eats an apple with the pips. Eventually he looks closer at the trees and realises they're all people who stole the apples and he's becoming a tree too.
- A girl gets a mood ring that makes her laugh uncontrollably, she tries to cut her finger off because there's no other way to remove it, but her mom stops her.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure those are all stories from the *Midnight Library* series by Damien Graves if you're still curious.

The apple tree story is "An Apple a Day" in *[Midnight Library: Voices](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1770575837?book_show_action=true)*

> The last story, an apple a day is different from the last two stories. It is about a young boy named Tim who is mad about his neighbor scaring his grandma after his neighbor accusses [sic] him of eating one of his apples. Tim tries to get him back by spelling out the word "bully" with his own apples in his backyard and eating one of the apples. range things start happening the next day when he starts coughing up apple seeds and growing leaves out of his ear. The book slowly turns Tim into a literal apple tree.

The cat story and the confronting the fears stories are likely in *[The Cat Lady](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0439893917)*

> Chloe has heard some shocking rumors about the neighborhood Cat Lady. Shocking rumors that could prove true.
>
> Mark and Calvin are impressed by a new friend who doesn't play by the rules -- until they discover what kind of game she's playing.

The mood ring story is "True Colors" in *[Midnight Library: I Can See You](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/53451520?book_show_action=true)*:

> Carrie makes a bargain purchase at the farmers' market, but when the old vendor refuses to part with a "mood" ring that appears to be included with the purchase, Carrie is upset. Later when she finds the very ring lying on the ground, she snatches it up and slips it on her finger. Soon Carrie begins to regret that she didn't listen to the old woman's warning.